# Laravel Handle Exceptions

Tags: php, exception, laravel

I am using the Stripe API and Laravel together. If Stripe detects an error charging the card (such as using a test credit card number that throws an invalid security code error), the API bindings are supposed to throw an exception, which they do. The problem is, I am having issues *catching* the exception before Laravel throws up the error 500 page (I am trying to perform a redirect with an error message instead).

The code I've written is available on Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ZaW2xbbt

The behavior I'm expecting is for the `catch` to fire and the redirect to be performed, but instead, I get the stack trace with the message and "Unhandled Exception". That's confusing me because I *am* handling the exception.

Variables such as `$customer` are valid and have been defined previously. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: To catch laravel exception, use `\Exception`

Comment: That still seems to show the default stack trace, regardless what namespace I prefix `Extension` with (root or otherwise)

Comment: So you're importing those exceptions into the current namespace scope then?

Comment: That pastebin doesn't appear to be valid.  Are you using Laravel 3 or Laravel 4?

Comment: The Pastebin was set to expire, though the issue was in a Laravel 4 application. I did solve the problem, and I'll have to go back and find the solution and post it here.

Answer (score 6):

For any future viewers, here's an article on [error handling in laravel 4](http://fideloper.com/laravel4-error-handling).

Laravel 4 lets you catch Exceptions by exception type. For instance, you can handle Symfony's `HttpException` and of its sub-classes by adding this to your code:

```
// Catch HttpException, NotFoundHttpException, etc etc
App::error(function(HttpException $exception, $code, $fromConsole)
{
    ...
});
```

Symfony HttpExceptions (used in Laravel) can be found [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception).

You can also throw this in a ServiceProvider:

```
<?php namespace My\Namespace;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
            $this->app->error(function(HttpException $exception, $code, $fromConsole)
            {
                ...
            });
    }

}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, all errors logged by Laravel are logged under `storage/logs` folder

Anyway, the 500 error could be a syntax/parse error, in such case the Laravel framework could be not yet loaded when the error occurs and if so, the exception is not lhandled by Laravel.

In this case you should access the apache/vargrant/whatif php error log in some way (dependently on your server capabilities and configuration), in my personal cases I have configured the server to put that logs in a `/storage/logs/error_log.txt` file such that I can access them as other Laravel server logs

Note that in Laravel 5, you have `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` as entry point for customize exception handling/reporting

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors#the-exception-handler